# VBA Passing parameter in query to ADO connection '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

It seems that in the command text, I am not able to use a parameter as a table name so I am now trying to hard code it into the VBA the query but I am running into the '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. Attached is a screenshot of the command text I am using but doesn't seem to work. The code below I added is causing the error:
[The Connection Properties pop up box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Swr.png)

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query1").OLEDBConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [DBO].[Refresh_" & UserName & "] ORDER BY [Item No];"
End With
```

I would appreciate any help anyone can give me in regards to the query within the "Connections" properties box or the vba code. Either would work.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: It doesnt really say, '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error on popup box.

Comment: When you click "Debug" which line is highlighted?

Comment: What do you mean? The debug tool bar, I can try some of the actions but it doesn't take me to exactly where it fails. Sorry, dont use debug, I usually just use print statements to debug.

Comment: So it seems it just doesnt like the With statement, I did it with the "With" and only "With End" part and it still gives me the same error. I put ```MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query1"))``` before the "With" statement and the popup msgbox gave me the connection name "Query1", just dont know why the "With" statement is throwing the error.

Comment: Try  `With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query1").ODBCConnection` (ie. not OLEDBConnection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you set up the connection, it will either have an `ODBCConnection`, or an `OLEDBConnection` property (but not both).

If you break down the code a little you can put a watch on the connection and see what properties are populated:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection 'put a Watch on this and step through....
    
    Set conn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("TestQuery")
    
    With conn.ODBCConnection
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .CommandType = xlCmdSql    '<<<<  not adCmdText
            .CommandText = "select * from ops$rs3.hts_scientist"
    End With

End Sub
```

Watch window:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and let you know what happens...

Comment: I resolved the issue, and now looking at your post, it makes sense. Turns out it was using ODBC connection instead of OLEDB. Thank you for all your help!